# Is the map $\operatorname{Sym}^k(H^0(X, L)) \to H^0(X, L^k)$ injective, when $L$ is generated by global setions?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra

This appears in Positivity 1 by Rob Lazarsfeld, after the statement of theorem 2.1.26. $L$ is assumed to be a globally generated line bundle on a projective (integral) variety $X$ over $k$. Then, since $s \otimes t = t \otimes s$ in $L^{\otimes 2}$, there is a natural map of $k$-vector spaces $$\operatorname{Sym}^n(H^0(X, L)) \longrightarrow H^0(X, L^n)$$ by sending $s_{i_1} \odot \dots \odot s_{i_n}$ to $s_{i_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes s_{i_n}$.

It is claimed in the book that this is an injective map. I am having trouble proving this. Below are some thoughts I had in the direction of a proof, but none of it was conclusive.

Tt suffices to show that if $e_1, \dots, e_r$ are a basis of $H^0(X, L)$, then the collection of 'monomials' $e_{i_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes e_{i_n}$ form a linearly independent set in $H^0(X, L^n)$.

I thought to use the fact that $X$ is integral, so the restriction maps are injective, and then argue that if $R$ is an integral $k$-algebra, and $e_1, \dots, e_r \in R$ are $k$-linearly independent, then the result follows form showing the collection of monomials are linearly independent.

In a similar but different direction, considering this map for each $n$ we have a map of graded $k$-algebras $\operatorname{Sym}(V) = k[e_1, \dots, e_r] \to R(X, L)$ which is injective in degrees 0 and 1. Can we go from here and conclude that this map is injective in all degrees?

My concern here is when $R(X, L)$ is not a UFD, so maybe two distinct monomials of the same degree in $k[e_1, \dots, e_r]$ go to the same element of $R(X, L)$.

Thanks!

Edit: This claim does not explicitly appear in the book; this is just how I interpreted it, which may be an incorrect interpretation. As such, if this is incorrect, it is not the author's fault.

Also, in the book, $X$ is assumed to be a normal variety. That way, it'll be smooth, and hence a UFD in codimension 1, so perhaps here the monomials will have to be distinct in the coordinate ring. If $X$ is not normal, this is not true.

For example, if $X$ is the nodal curve $Z(xyz^4 - (x^6 + y^6)) \subset \mathbb{P}^2$, then the map $\operatorname{Sym}^6(H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(1))) \to H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(6))$ is definitely not injective.

Comment: As you said,  your interpretation is false. Just try projective line and $O(1)$.

Comment: @Mohan Isn't this okay though? $\operatorname{Sym}^2(H^0(P^1, O(1)))$ has basis $s^2, t^2, st$, which gets sent to the canonical basis of $H^0(P^1, O(1))$, right?

Comment: Sorry,  I meant the comic in the plane.

Comment: Ah I see; the dimension of $\operatorname{Sym}^2(H^0(P^1, O(2)))$ is larger than that of $H^0(P^1, O(4))$. If you're willing to record this as an answer, I'd be happy to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask is mostly false as below.

Let $X$ be a projective variety of dimension $d$ and $L$ an ample globally generated line bundle. Then $h^0(L)=r>d$. Replacing $L$ by $L^2$, we may assume $r>d+1$. Then $h^0(L^n)$ grows like $n^d$ while $\dim S^nH^0(L)$ grows like $n^{r-1}$ and since $r-1>d$, the latter is bigger than the former for all large $n$ and thus $S^nH^0(L)\to H^0(L^n)$ can not be injective for large $n$.